# implement listener

Tags: javascript, yui

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;
charset=utf-8">
<title>YUI Calendar Control Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css"
href="yui/build/calendar/assets/skins/sam/calendar.css">
<script type="text/javascript"
src="yui/build/yahoo-dom-event/
yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="yui/build/calendar/calendar-min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
input {
margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="yui-skin-sam">
<div>
<label>Please enter your date of birth:</label>
<input type="text" name="dobfield" id="dobfield">
<img id="calico" src="E:\HP_PROJECT\cal.png"
alt="Open the Calendar control">
</div>
<div id="mycal"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//create the namespace object for this example
YAHOO.namespace("yuibook.calendar");
//define the lauchCal function which creates the calendar
YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.launchCal = function() {
//create the calendar object, specifying the container
Var myCal = new YAHOO.widget.Calendar("mycal");
//draw the calendar on screen
myCal.render();


}
//define the showCal function which shows the calendar
Var showCal = function() {
//show the calendar
myCal.show();
}

//create calendar on page load
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.launchCal);
 //attach listener for click event on calendar icon
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("calico", "click", showCal);  
//myCal.hide();



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have used the above code. But the problem with the code is that when I click image icon nothing is displayed. I am new to javascript. Please help me how to implement listener.

Please guide me where to do chages in the code.

Thanks 
Padmaja

Comment: please reformat your code to make it readable.

Comment: I think I copied it as intendcded ...

Comment: wait - shouldn't you leave the original incorrect code in the question, and my correct code in my answer?

Comment: if you do want to reformat, please copy his original code from my post.

Comment: How should this be downvoted? +1

Comment: it looks like the above code is sourced from http://www.packtpub.com/article/implementing-calendar-control-yahoo-user-interface which contains a bunch of errors, mainly the use of `Var` instead of `var` in the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `myCal` is a local variable to the `launchCal()` function.  Giving the myCal variable a globally-accessible namespace will make it available to every scope.

**Here's your original code** (someone else accidentally put my correct code in your original question =/)

```
YAHOO.namespace("yuibook.calendar"); 

//define the lauchCal function which creates the calendar 
YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.launchCal = function() { 

    //create the calendar object, specifying the container 
    var myCal = new YAHOO.widget.Calendar("mycal"); 

    //draw the calendar on screen 
    myCal.render(); 
}

//define the showCal function which shows the calendar
Var showCal = function() { 
    //show the calendar 
    myCal.show(); 
} 

//create calendar on page load
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.launchCal); 

//attach listener for click event on calendar icon 
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("calico", "click", showCal); 

//myCal.hide();
```

**Now see my changes.**  Note the use of the global YAHOO namespace.

```
YAHOO.namespace("yuibook.calendar"); 

//define the lauchCal function which creates the calendar 
YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.launchCal = function() { 

    //create the calendar object, specifying the container 
    YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.myCal = new YAHOO.widget.Calendar("mycal"); 

    //draw the calendar on screen 
    myCal.render(); 
}

//define the showCal function which shows the calendar
Var showCal = function() { 
    //show the calendar 
    YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.myCal.show(); 
} 

//create calendar on page load
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.launchCal); 

//attach listener for click event on calendar icon 
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("calico", "click", showCal); 

//myCal.hide();
```

Comment: Your answer should be in your answer, not his question. Now I have no idea what he was asking because you've changed the question to an "answer". What did he do wrong in the original question? How can someone learn from his mistake?

Comment: I didn't do that, le dorfier did.  Hopefully he changes it back.  I don't have enough authority or whatever to edit other people's posts.  

Anyway - I rolled mine back to show my answer.

Comment: this answer identifies the problem but the code has a couple issues. the statement `myCal.render();` needs to be updated to `YAHOO.yuibook.calendar.myCal.render();`. also `Var showCal ... ` needs to be made `var showCal ... ` since js is case-sensitive and the correct keyword is `var` with a little v. this mistake is repeated in the source material (see comment on OP) several times. and not an issue with your answer but there is nothing in the original code to hide the calendar before the `image is clicked, so it's always visible.